# Modelica kinematics simulation environment for commercial distribution

Tags: modelica

I am looking to develop a tool to run a fairly simple multibody kinematics simulation and plot outputs such as forces. The tool is intended for commercial distribution by a third-party company, and would act as a calculator for setting up the machine it simulates.

I am considering basing the tool on Modelica. Are there any simulation platforms available that would allow distribution without royalties? If not, is there a better alternative to Modelica?

Comment: Distribution of what? The full platform itself or the executable (generated) simulations?

Comment: @sjoelund.se : Distribution of an application that would allow the user to enter different motion profiles and plot the resulting forces.

Comment: I think that with more or less any Modelica based tool you can do that. Open Modelica can be used since it exports in binary and FMI format (you can find your models in C:\Users\<User name>\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit) but I'm not sure about the kind of license it has, depending on that you might give credits that you application was made with OpenModelica. Dymola(Modelica commercial tool)+BinaryModelExport license does that. Note that in both cases you have to code yourself a GUI to handle the textual input file from which the binary files you generated read the param of the model.

Comment: FYI, if you can export your model as an FMU (via the methods described above), my company (www.xogeny.com) has developed technology to allow you to build web-based simulation GUIs (and the infrastructure necessary to execute them "in the cloud").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wolfram SystemModeler](http://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler) can create stand alone simulation executables (without any additional add-ons) that you can distribute without royalties.

Disclaimer: I work for Wolfram Research

Comment: That sounds like it might work for me, especially since I have Mathematica. I will try it out. Thanks.